# Unable to start webex on firefox 36

Tags: firefox, ubuntu-14.04, webex

I am unable to start webex and getting following error while entering in room on webex **"Your browser, browser version, or operating system is currently unsupported."**
I am using firefox 36 on ubuntu 14.04.  I tried using webex testing site (http://www.webex.com/test-meeting.html#) which works fine and I am able to launch webex screen. I am not sure why am I getting unsupported browser error. Please help

**SOLUTION**
This works for 14.x.

Follow steps here http://linuxsagas.digitaleagle.net/2014/02/07/webex-on-64-bit-ubuntu-13-10/

Comment: I followed these steps and it started working fine http://linuxsagas.digitaleagle.net/2014/02/07/webex-on-64-bit-ubuntu-13-10/

Comment: Doesn't solve my problem. :\ BTW, why is this on SO?

Answer (score 4):

I actually was able to solve this problem. It turns out that if you are able to run a webex test from here: 
http://www.webex.com/test-meeting.html

And you are not able to test from here:
https://cisco.webex.com/meet/yourusername

The problem is already solved! Somehow if you hit "Enter room". It will not work HOWEVER if someone gives you a link to their personal room or a direct webex link it will work!.

Not sure what happens, when you try to create a webex directly on you room but as a workaround you can do this:

Go to "Schedule a meeting" on the left side and follow the instructions, somehow it will reserve the resources and will let you join it.

My firefox is 64 bit running icedtea-7 plugin i386. I must also share that  some features are incomplete like the Whiteboard and sharing a specific monitor does not work.

I know that this may be related to missing libraries, but so far, I can report that other features work fine.